# Domain names on 2 similar windows domains (active directory)

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller

I am fairly new to windows administration (Server 2008r2), but I am putting together a new environment, and am setting up active directory domains.

I have broken my system into 2 parts, management (mgt) and operational (ops).
They are both parts of the same system, but their availability needs are a bit different.

I decided to call my system "vmnet". 
I created 2 domains, vmnet.ops and vmnet.mgt.

I assumed that these would be completely separate domains, much like .com and .org websites.

Unfortunately, as I was configuring a file share on vmnet.mgt, I realized that a user with the same name on vmnet.ops did NOT have to enter credentials to access the share.

So: 
1) Folder on a mgt domain server shared to jake@vmnet.mgt via windows share.
2) Logged into a ops domain workstation (jake@vmnet.ops), and try to access the shared folder.
3) It lets me in with no entry of credentials.
4) Looking at the shared folder permissions from the vmnet.ops box, it says it is shared with jake@vmnet.ops
5) Looking  at the actual shared folder from the vmnet.mgt machine, it claims it is shared with only jake@vmnet.mgt.

There seems to be overlap here. Different domains, should have completely different UID? No overlap at all?
Or have I messed up, and vmnet.ops and vmnet.mgt are the same domain, and the .mgt/.ops are irrelevant?

Comment: I think we're going to need some screenshots of Active Directory Users and Computers or something - I'm very confused by what you've created

Comment: Same name & same passwords? Try to change the password on one system and see if you can reproduce it.

Comment: What is exactly is the "system" you are calling "vmnet"?

Comment: It is a group of servers/workstations.
I have broken it into 2 separate groups -- devices that are mission critical, and ones that are used purely for administration/management.
Database and application servers -- "ops" domain. They have redundant domain controllers, redundant network devices, etc.
Backup server, management workstation -- "mgt" domain. May be important, but we can still provide 100% service if they are interrupted.

Comment: why would you split that anyway? you just need more domain controllers... and you don't really gain anything. Have you tried changing the password?

Comment: Security reasons -- we have several external users who need to authenticate to the system to perform security/administrative functions (update virus scanner, check status of VMs, view audits). We wanted to keep these users off the ops domain, and restrict external connectivity to the ops devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a jake user on each domain with the same password, jake from one domain will be able to access shares on the other domain because the password is the same.  It works like this:

1. If jake@domain1 is accessing resources in domain1, a password is not sent to the system hosting the resource because jake got a security token when he logged in to the domain, and the security token is used to gain access.
2. If jake@domain1 is accessing resources that are NOT on domain1 (i.e., in domain2, or a system that isn't in a domain), it will pass jakes username and password to the other system, and if the credentials match for a jake user on that domain or computer, then jake will get access to those resources.

Comment: So, it is purely username/password based, and does not include domain specific info in the authentication process?
I can work with that.


What about group memberships? When I look at the permissions on domain 1, I have VMNET\sysadmin
when I look at the share on domain 2, I still see VMNET\sysadmin.
If that group exists on both computers, what happens? And why does it only display VMNET\, not VMNET.MGT\  ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think jake@domain1 will not be considered a member of a group on domain2.  I would highly recommend that you run a quick test on things like this that only take a couple of minutes of testing.  Not only will you get the answer, the best way to learn is by doing.  As for the display of only "VMNET" instead of "VMNET.MGT", Windows simply doesn't show the domain suffix name in some places.

Comment: I am certainly testing this currently, but fighting cached credentials. Your answer above cleared things up for me. I was very concerned I had some sort of domain overlap, and would have to change the entire thing. Better now then later, though.

Comment: Test seem to be working -- things are separate. I will update this if I manage to get groups to overlap, though.